# Compute the length of largest substring that starts and ends with the same substring

Tags: java, algorithm, string, recursion

Below is the Problem Statement:

**PS: Given a string and a non-empty substring sub, compute recursively the largest substring which starts and ends with sub and return its length.**

`Examples:`
`strDist("catcowcat", "cat") → 9`
`strDist("catcowcat", "cow") → 3`
`strDist("cccatcowcatxx", "cat") → 9`

Below is my Code:
       (Without recursion)//since i found it hard to implement with recursion.

```
    public int strDist(String str, String sub){    
        int idx = 0;     
        int max;    
        if (str.isEmpty()) max = 0;    
        else max=1;                        
        while ((idx = str.indexOf(sub, idx)) != -1){     
            int previous=str.indexOf(sub, idx);     
            max = Math.max(max,previous);     
            idx++;                           
        }     
     return max;    
   }
```

**Its working for few as shown below but returns FAIL for others.**

`Expected This Run`
`strDist("catcowcat", "cat") → 9 6 FAIL`
`strDist("catcowcat", "cow") → 3 3 OK`
`strDist("cccatcowcatxx", "cat") → 9 8 FAIL`
`strDist("abccatcowcatcatxyz", "cat") → 12 12 OK`
`strDist("xyx", "x") → 3 2 FAIL`
`strDist("xyx", "y") → 1 1 OK`
`strDist("xyx", "z") → 0 1 FAIL`
`strDist("z", "z") → 1 1 OK`
`strDist("x", "z") → 0 1 FAIL`
`strDist("", "z") → 0 0 OK`
`strDist("hiHellohihihi", "hi") → 13 11 FAIL`
`strDist("hiHellohihihi", "hih") → 5 9 FAIL`
`strDist("hiHellohihihi", "o") → 1 6 FAIL`
`strDist("hiHellohihihi", "ll") → 2 4 FAIL`

**Could you let me whats wrong with the code and how to return the largest substring that begins and ends with sub with its respective length.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a simple solution that's much more efficient. Find the first and last occurrence of the substring and you have your answer. No need to search for all occurrences.

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
  int first = str.indexOf(sub);
  if (first == -1)
    return 0;
  int last = str.lastIndexOf(sub);
  return last - first + sub.length();
}
```

http://ideone.com/3mgbK

The problem with your code is that you are returning the index of the last occurrence of the substring. You appear to be trying to find the 2nd last occurrence as well, and your last line should be `max - previous` at the least, but then you'd also need to add the length of the substring making it `max - previous + sub.length()`. You also need to move the declaration of `previous` outside the while loop. But then you're finding the distance between the 2nd last and last occurrences, which will fail if there aren't exactly 2 occurrences (e.g. `"foocatbar"` or `"catfoocatbarcat"`).

Solving this recursively is a bit overkill, first and foremost because you cannot use the builtin `String.indexOf()` function. But since this is homework, here's a quick attempt:

```
public static int indexOf(String str, String sub, int start, int direction) {
  if (start < 0 || start > str.length() - sub.length())
    return -1;
  if (str.substring(start, start + sub.length()).equals(sub))
    return start;
  return indexOf(str, sub, start+direction, direction);
}

public static int strDistRecursive(String str, String sub) {
  int first = indexOf(str, sub, 0, 1);
  if (first == -1)
    return 0;
  int last = indexOf(str, sub, str.length() - sub.length(), -1);
  return last - first + sub.length();
}
```

http://ideone.com/f6bok

Comment: @marcog,could you please let me know how do i do that.confused :-(

Comment: its not working. strDist("catcowcat", "cat") → 9 3 FAIL,your solution works if it occurs only once.not for all cases

Comment: Thanks @finnw, I was just fixing it when you fixed it. :) There was also a missing `;` which I fixed.

Comment: Oh gosh it was so easy i did not finish it in time.i was breaking my head with while loops and indexOf and came close it,Thanks All.any idea on how to achieve it recursively

Comment: @Deepak you already closed this one. And the recursive approach was not what you asked here ...

Comment: @belisarius,you can post an alternative solution

Comment: @belisarius,i did a check on it,since you wanted to post an alternate solution,i thought of re-opening the question.sorry for the connfusion,BTW my question/Problem Statement did ask for a recursive one

Comment: @Deepak I think if you want some help with the recursive solution, you may post another question. But, as recursive thinking takes a while to appropriate, I suggest not asking for the code but for some hints, and try to get your own code running. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Marcog for that recursive function

Comment: `strDistRecursive` is a bit misleading. It's not recursive, it doesn't call itself. The indexOf function is recursive.

Comment: @Ishtar It's indirectly recursive. Perhaps slightly misleading, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Shouldn't catwomencatwhiskerscat result in 8 for whiskers?

Answer (score 2):

I post here my solution that is recursive. The logic behind it is to chop from left until sub is found at the start and to chop from right until sub is found at the end.

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) 
{
    if (0 == str.length())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (!str.startsWith(sub))
    {
        //chop from left
        return strDist(str.substring(1), sub);    
    }
    else if (!str.endsWith(sub))
    {
        //chop from right
        return strDist(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), sub);
    }
    else if (str.startsWith(sub) && str.endsWith(sub))
    {
        //got a substring subXXXsub
        return str.length();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The  simple solution to this problem is calculating the first index and lastindex of sub string in the main string .But if you really need to do it with recursion , here's the code .

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
   int n = str.length();
   if(n==0) return 0; 
   if (str.startsWith(sub)) return strBack(str,sub);
   return strDist(str.substring(1) , sub);
 }

public int strBack(String str, String sub) { 
int n = str.length();
if (n ==0) return 0;
if(str.endsWith(sub)) return n ;
 return strBack(str.substring(0,n-1),sub);
  }
```

The whole approach is  that strDist function starts looking for sub string from the start and strBack starts looking for sub from the end and if not found str is stripped by one char. So once sub is found at start in strDist then strBack is called and sub is looked from the end and if found the stripped str is what the longest string we require . Its length is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
hi I implemented the same problem with some other manner .. 

{{{

   public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
   int i = str.indexOf(sub);
   if(i==-1)  return 0;

   if(str.endsWith(sub))
      return str.length(); 

   return strDist(str.substring(i,str.length()-1),sub);
   }

}}}

this gives all correct but was wrong for other testes... Dont know y..
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice short recursive solution. 
It's not something innovative to some other presented solutions, but its shorter and more clear, so easier to understand:

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
  if (str.length()==0) return 0;
  if (!str.startsWith(sub))
      return strDist(str.substring(1),sub);
  if (!str.endsWith(sub))
    return strDist(str.substring(0,str.length()-1),sub);
  return str.length();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of the solution. It should work correctly - but, int the site(CODINGBAT) i can't pass the checkup.

```html
<code>
public int strDist(String str, String sub)
{

if(str.length()<1||!str.contains(sub))return 0; 
  if(str.substring(0,sub.length()).equals(sub))
  {
   String s=str.substring(1);
   if(!s.contains(sub))
   return sub.length();
   else
   { 
    
    int t=s.indexOf(sub)+sub.length()+1;
    return t+strDist(s.substring(s.indexOf(sub)+sub.length()),sub);
   }  
  } 
  return strDist(str.substring(1),sub); 

 
}</code>
```